Caress me gently
I designed this riddle for my now-wife in November 2019. Each clue can be used on its own to find the solution; you don’t need all the clues to solve it. However, as you progress, the clues gradually become easier, offering more guidance toward the answer. I intentionally made the riddle challenging and, at times, frustrating, but I'm sure this won't stop experienced riddle-solvers :).
Originally, I provided one clue at the beginning of each week, but since that's not possible here, I've outlined some optional rules to mimic the original challenge:

Reveal the clues in the order provided, one at a time, rather than all at once.
Partial guesses are not accepted; you must fully explain at least one of the clues to qualify.

Riddle

 Caress me gently, learn my secrets, or I'll keep you company in the afterlife.


 Digitally I'm two of me, but also 100 more than my other self.


 My Twin spins in complex ways, creating worlds connected to its base.


 I just celebrated Winnie's life achievement, yet people see me as evil, a witch's curse.


 And when they wake, cast me without fear, because I'll make you win in pairs.


 I am God's first perfect creation, His infinite divine divisor.

On what day of the month was I born?
Optional context (not a clue)

 Both I and the recipient of this riddle have studied and worked in computer science.


rot13(V guvax gur frpbaq pyhr cbvagf gb gur ahzore 10 - 1010 - "qvtvgnyyl V'z 2 bs zr" - 1010 va ovanel vf 10 va qrpvzny - "ohg nyfb 100 zber guna zl bgure frys" - 100 va ovanel vf 4 - gur svefg gjb qvtvgf bs 1010 jbhyq vzcyl "8", yvxr n ovanel "1000" - gur ynfg gjb qvtvgf znxr "2" - gb gvr onpx gb 100/4, 8 vf 4 gvzrf 2.)

@ConnieMnemonic rot13: Vg jbhyq znxr frafr sbe gur ynfg pyhr; nf vg'f irel rnfl gb qvivfr ol 10. Nyfb, -whfg n thrff-, ohg gur guveq pyhr znxrf zr guvax bs (10) naq (01) nf irpgbe sebz na begubabzny onfvf. Pyhr 5 zvtug -vg'f n thrff v'z rira yrff pbasvqrag va- or n erssrerapr gb gnoyr gbc ectf jurer qbhoyr 10'f jbhyq or n pevgvpny uvg

rot13: V'z abg fher vs gurer ner nal ECTf yvxr gung. Vg'f pregnvayl abg pbzzba. Nyfb jbegu abgvat vg'f rnfl gb qvivqr va jungrire onfr lbh'er va. Jr hfr onfr 10 fb vg'f rnfl sbe hf gb qvivqr ol vg. Vs jr hfrq onfr 2, vg'q or rnfl sbe hf gb qvivqr ol 2. Gurer'f qrsvavgryl n ybg bs ovanel furanavtnaf tbvat ba urer, uru.

V qb nterr nobhg gur qvivfvba ol 10. Ohg vg vf fhccbfrq gb or gur rnfvrfg pyhr. V'z whfg gelvat gb svaq cbffvoyr pbaarpgvbaf jvgu gur bguref

Ofc. Hope I didn't come across mean there, more just trying to be skeptical of my own idea, heh heh

I think the answer is

 the 6th of the month

Partial explanation:
Clues 1 and 4:

 666 is the number of the beast

Clue 2:

 In binary, 6 is 110, while the ASCII code for "6" is 110110.

Clue 5:

 Many games involve rolling two six-sided dice and doing well if you get two sixes.

Clue 6:

 In Genesis, God created the world in six days. Six is the first perfect number (sum of its proper divisors).


What about clue 3?

Jryy, gurer hfrq gb or avar cynargf

Guvf vf tbvat va gur evtug qverpgvba. Gurer vf gehgu va gur cnegvny nafjref sbe pyhrf 2, 5 naq 6, nygubhtu vapbzcyrgr
